# Sampling rows from dataframe and saving unselected ones

Tags: r

I'm triying to randomly choose rows from a dataframe; however, I also need unselected ones. I proceeded as follows

```
#grades is data with size 100
half-grades = grades[sample(nrow(grades), 50), ]
```

How do I save unselected ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for an even 50% split, the code is as follows.

```
library(caTools)
split = sample.split(grades,SplitRatio=0.5)
half-grades1 = subset(grades, split == TRUE)
half-grades2 = subset(grades, split == FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily accomplished with `caret::createDataPartition()`.

```
library(caret)
theIndex <- createDataPartition(grades, p = .50,list=FALSE)
sampled <- grades[theIndex,]
notSampled <- grades[-theIndex,]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set.seed(1234)
half-grades=grades[-(sample(nrow(grades), 50)), ]
```